Excel 2010 VSTO CreatePivotTable fails
In a Excel Addin app, I am trying to create a Pivot table using a viw in my (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB database.
The following CreatePivotTable statement fails with an exception message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC --
PivotCache cache = workbook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, connection);
PivotTable pt = cache.CreatePivotTable(targetSheet.Range["A1"], "NewPivotTable1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);      //, true, XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion14);


I have tried with and without the commented out arguments without success. Can any one please shed some light on this?
n.b. other examples of a solution relate to source data in other worksheets, rather than in a database

After lots of failed experiments, I have a solution based on comment above - thank you, MyExcelDeveloper.com -  that works, as follows:
    public void CreatePivotTable_Example()
    {
        string targetSheetName = "<my sheet name>";
        Worksheet targetSheet = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        targetSheet.Name = targetSheetName;
        targetSheet.Activate();

        WorkbookConnection connection = null;
        string connectionName = "<insert connection name>";
        string connectionDesc = "<insert description>";
        string connectionString = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;" +
            "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
            "Initial Catalog=<my database name>;" +
            "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +
            "";

        string commandText = "<my sql select string>";

        try
        {
            var cache = workbook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, Type.Missing);
            cache.Connection = connectionString;
            cache.MaintainConnection = true;
            cache.MakeConnection();
            cache.CommandText = commandText;
            cache.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdSql;
            var pivotTables = (PivotTables)targetSheet.PivotTables(Type.Missing);
            PivotTable pt = pivotTables.Add(cache, Ribbon.application.ActiveCell, "NewPivotTableV1");       //, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }


I used
Range xlPivotdata;
Excel.PivotCache xlPivotCache;
Excel.PivotCaches xlPivotCaches;
Excel.PivotTable xlPivotTable;

xlPivotSheet = XL.ActiveSheet;

xlPivotCaches = xlActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches;
xlPivotdata = xlPivotSheet.Range("A1:" + GetColumnLetter(maxCol) + maxRow);

xlPivotCache = xlPivotCaches.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, xlPivotdata);
xlPivotTable = xlPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(xlPivotSheet.Range("Z1"), "ES_Pivot");

Are you sure the pivot cache is not empty?

This does not answer the question - the issue is specific to using LocalDB as the pivot table source

Reading your answer I assume your pivotcache is filled (so the connection variable includes sql) and gives a result. Now it has been a while ago that I tried it, but could you break it down, something like: lExcel.PivotCache pivotCache = workbook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, Type.Missing);
pivotCache.Connection = connection;
pivotCache.MakeConnection();
pivotCache.MaintainConnection = true;
pivotCache.CommandText = command;
